# How add audio(custom) tag in ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

Plugin:

```js
export default class AudioUploader extends Plugin {

  static get pluginName() {
    return 'AudioUploader';
  }

  static get requires() {
    return [];
  }

  init() {
    const editor = this.editor;
    const schema = editor.model.schema;

    schema.register('audio', {
      allowIn: ['$root', '$block', 'blockQuote', 'paragraph'],
      isBlock: true,
      allowAttributes: ['controls', 'src'],
    });

    editor.conversion.elementToElement({
      model: 'audio',
      view: {
        name: 'audio',
      },
    });

    editor.conversion.for( 'dataDowncast' ).elementToElement({
      model: 'audio',
      view: {
        name: 'audio',
      },
    });

    editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).elementToElement({
      model: 'audio',
      view: {
        name: 'audio',
      },
    });

    editor.ui.componentFactory.add('AudioUploader', () => {
      const view = new FileDialogButtonView();

      view.buttonView.set({
        tooltip: 'Добавить аудио',
        icon: MusicIcon,
      });

      view.on('done', (evt, files) => {
        getBase64(Array.from(files)[0], (audio) => {
          editor.model.change(writer => {
            const elem = writer.createElement('audio', {
              src: audio,
              controls: true,
            });

            editor.model.insertContent(elem, editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition());
          });
        });
      });

      return view;
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

If you insert just text(`writer.insertText('some text', editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition());`), then everything will be inserted correctly.

Everything is correct in the ckeditor5 inspector. I don’t understand the philosophy of adding arbitrary tags to the editor.

Why isn't it showing up in the editor?
Why is the content not correct in console?

Comment: any luck yet? trying the same..

Comment: editor.conversion.elementToElement({
      model: 'audio',
      view: {
        name: 'audio',
      },
    });

Answer (score 0):

This will do the conversion without the attributes.

```
editor.conversion.elementToElement({
      model: 'audio',
      view: {
        name: 'audio',
      },
    });
```

Instead you have to use the function version like:

```
        conversion.for( 'audio' ).elementToElement( {
            view: {
                name: 'audio',
            },
            model: ( viewElement, { writer: modelWriter } ) => {
                const src = viewElement?.getAttribute('src');
                //etc for all the attributes
                const e = modelWriter.createElement( 'audio', { src } );
                return e;
            }
        } );
```

I don't know if there's a better way.  And note that this will ignore the children as well I think.  I'm new myself.